# Validate a dropdownlist on tab out

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to validate my DropDownlist on tabout.The dropdownlist is as shown

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Select a Provider Type:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10" id="ProviderType">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>Select a Provider Type</option>
                    <option>Doctor</option>
                    <option>Facility</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have written the following codes to get the alert on tab out

```
$("#ProviderType").on("blur", function () {
    if ($("this")[0].selectedindex <= 0)
        alert("Please choose a Provider");
});
```

The above code did not work,

So I tried this code which did not work either

```
$("#ProviderType option:selected").on("blur", function () {
    if ($("this").text() == "Select a Provider Type")
        alert("Please choose a Provider");
});
```

Any help would be appreciated guys.Thanks in advance.

As suggested I did some Event handling using .bind() method.

```
 $("#Certification").bind("blur",function () {
    alert("Event binding is working fine.")
});
```

I see an alert when tabbing out of the Dropdownlist.I still dont see the error though.Please guide me.

Comment: How did it not work? Are you getting any errors on console?

Comment: Nope .. No errors.I have got a warning related to knockout.Thats about it.

Comment: Does the element exist when your code runs? Try delegating the event

Comment: PLease check my edit.I have added an Event binding.

Comment: You've bound `blur` event to `#Certification`. What is `#Certification` in your code? Is it the select block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 - Set empty value to first option**

A solution can be to set an empty value to first option and then check selected value

```
$("#Certification").bind("blur",function () {
    var selected_value = $(this).val();
    if(selected_value==null || selected_value=='') {
        alert("Please choose a Provider");
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uchooyvg/)

This can be used to check value just after the element loses focus. This solution however may be annoying for users, since they may want to come back and make a new selection. So, you may evaluate a second solution.

**Solution 2 - Hide first option**

Another solution may be to hide the first option from list, so that users can't choose it and then check selected value after all, i.e. on form submission.

```
$("#myform").submit(function()  {
    var selected_value = $("#Certification").val();
    if(selected_value==null || selected_value=='') {
        alert("Please choose a Provider");
        return false;
    }
    return false; // remove this line in real form submission
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uchooyvg/1/)**